# MYSQL PHP Compare array of IDs to table and return new array in Order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a JavaScript array of numbers which correlate to IDs in a MYSQL table
ex:

```
[5,7,11,100,201,55,67] // ids
```

I want to compare this array with the MYSQL table, order by Date (or other arbitrary column), and return the same IDs but in order by Date. 
ex:

```
TABLE: someTable
- id column
- Date column
- ect column
```

How do I return just the IDs in order as efficiently as possible? 
And would this function lag if I tried to return a lot IDs in order, say over 20k?

Comment: Out of interest, how do you get those IDs into the JS in the first place? Can you not sort the data before you render the page in the first place? The idea of passing 20,000+ IDs over AJAX and efficiency don't go together

Comment: @jon -  I get the IDs from an associated Tags/category Tables - For example, If I return 20k 'ID' results from a query for "MYSQL" and I then want to Sort those IDs by Date, I have to compare it to the ID table which contains the Dates..   I was holding the results of the Tag query in a JavaScript array before I did the Sort.. maybe this is where I'm going wrong and perhaps I should compare the Dates at the same time I fetch the tags somehow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM someTable WHERE id IN (yourIdList) ORDER BY date;
```

Note that it may be possible to "cheat" if the date is a creation date and the ids are autoincrement. You could sort by id and this should be the same as sorting by date.

Comment: Even if they are auto incremented values, and the date is a timestamp, these aren't guaranteed to have the same order.  This is a dangerous assumption that can't be made.  It's easy to change what the next number to be used as the id is.

Comment: @jim  I can't believe I didn't think of that, to sort by Ascending/Descending order of IDs, in which case I don't even have to hit the database again, I can sort the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT someTable.id FROM someTable WHERE someTable.id in (5,7,11,100,201,55,67) ORDER BY someTable.date
```

You'll have to do some performance testing to see if it lags.